# it is backed by

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I can't understand what is "it is backed by" means in this sentence:

> The charred manuscript is carefully arranged in as near its original
>   shape as possible, on a sheet of glass and covered with a drying
>   varnish, after which it is backed by another sheet of glass.

In my imagination they should put another sheet of glass on the varnish, why to put it under the first glass? Back means behind the first glass, doesn't it? 
I need to translate this process of deciphering the charred paper. Please, help me understand
Thank you
It is a story of 1912

Comment: Perhaps the MS was arranged **face down** on the first sheet of glass so that the varnish is on its *back*, not its face, and then it is backed by another sheet. This does not seem to be a question about English though.

Comment: Perhaps the manuscript was laid on the original sheet of glass face down. Can you find a dictionary definition of the verb 'back' with the broadened meaning 'cover the back _or front_ of an article, usually to add support or to enhance appearance'? I can't (though there might be one). It's a bit late to check with the author what they meant.

Comment: Generally, varnish used to draw moisture out of an artefact would be applied to the back so as not to damage the front. Face-down on the first piece of glass then follows naturally.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain that verb for me!